# VBA - Filter a Table based of an other table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble copying values from one table found in Sheet("March") ( för exemple to another Sheet("Total of all months").

Sheet("Total of all months") has values ranging from 1-543 and each values has 12 rows specfic for each month, so values 1 has 12 rows with unique months ( Jan, Feb and so forth).

Sheet("March") on the other hand only has values 1-432, 510-542. ( Each much have different values ). I want to sort Sheet("Total of all months") to only show 1-432, 510-542 and the rows with March therefore making it easier to copy the values for Sheet("March") to Sheet("Total of all months").

I have tried a while loop that loops through all values in Sheets("March") and the finds the index in Sheet("Total of all months") using VBA .Find. But this is taking extremely long time. Is there a way of using autofilter as mentioned above?

I tried:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
 field:=2, _
 Criteria1:="Mar", _
 VisibleDropDown:=True
```

Which sorts the table in Sheet("Total of all months") to only show "Mar" but I also want to sort this table based on the values found in the range A2:A475 found in table "Mars" found in Sheet("Mars")

Comment: Hi Jordan, its a bit difficult for me to follow what you are trying to achieve, screenshots might help. Is copying from the March worksheet to the Total worksheet necessary, I think it might be easier to use a Pivot Table https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Comment: you can use advaced filter - Range("A1:C2").AdvancedFilter ....